# Android studio does not recognize generated custom class

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, code-generation

My problem is strictly connected with IDE. I have a custom class generator and its working correctly (Classes are in gen folder after build project). Unfortunately, Android Studio cannot resolve those classes in my project. But the funniest part is: When I hardcode correct import and use this class (even when compilator turns this part to red) and run a project... it works.

I tried clean project / rebuild / reset Android Studio... nothing helped. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: this is expected behavior since you don't provide a source of that class, and only give compiled one. Android Studio editor operates on sources, or  libraries. To solve your problem, you might want to use reflection to access classes & their methods by name

Answer (score 6):

### Solution:

In my `build.gradle` I had to add this generated directory into source set - in my case:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/apt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hade same problem after editing `gradle.build` module level,
after many searching i found out that a removed

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

and after re add every thing works fine